# Toggling not working properly in node--contenttype.tpl.php file

Tags: 7

I am theming a node of type "test".
I am using toggling in this "node--test.tpl.php" file.

Below is my code in "node--test.tpl.php":

```
    <div id ="block1" class="block_custom">
    <a href="javascript://" ><h1  class="active_custom">Property</h1></a>
    <div id="block1_content" style="background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);" >
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="tabledata">   
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="">
    <b>MLS #:</b>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <?php echo $node->field_listing_id['und']['0']['value'];?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

code in javascript file is

```
 (function ($) {
        $('#block1 > a').click(function()
       {
        $("#block1_content").toggle("slow");

         });

  })(jQuery);
```

Loading the java script files in template.php

```
drupal_add_js("themes/bartik/custom.js", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE); 
drupal_add_js("themes/bartik/jquery.min.js", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE);
```

jqueries and jquery plugins are enabled in modules.

but toggling is not working.

How to do toggling using jquery

Comment: your scripts are correct, ensure your scripts is loaded into site by checking source and no need to add jquery.min.js

Comment: @Anoop Joseph:scripts are loaded.

Comment: check if jquery working on the page by using an alert() in script

Comment: @Anoop Joseph: hm Jquery is not working on the page by using an alert.

Comment: the below one ans is right no need to add jquery.min.js, if you added already it is causing the above conflict because it already available in drupal.

Comment: @Anoop Joseph: I have removed jquery.min.js file. but still no use. cleared cache after removing jquery.min.js file also.

Comment: find out the reason what causing conflict on your page. when i run your script in firebug console its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing it when document get ready like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#block1 a').click(function()
       {
        $("#block1_content").toggle("slow");

         });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add "jquery.min.js". Drupal has by default this file.

Comment: I have removed jquery.min.js file. but still no use. cleared cache after removing jquery.min.js file also.  Do I need to install any module. I have "jqueries" and "jquery plugins" are enabled in modules.

Comment: plz verify your page resource and check your custom file exist or not. also try $('#block1 a').click(function()

Comment: Checked everything. but still no use. Tried this but not working

Comment: RE: check if jquery working on the page by using an alert() in script

Comment: Just placed alert . Its working. But when I Am using alert on button click its not working.

Comment: try "jQuery update" module...

Comment: Yeah Used this module also. But no use